# Extra spaces being added at the tail in the column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-design, sql-server-2000

When I am saving data into a table, extra spaces being added to the valued at the tail. I observed that as the column length is 5, if I am inserting a value of 3 char length, 2 extra spaces are being added. Can any one how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please provide insert statement and table definition.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Is the column type `CHAR(5)` instead of `VARCHAR(5)`?

- `CHAR(x)` creates a column that always stores x characters, and pads the data with spaces.
- `VARCHAR(x)` creates a column that varies the lengths of the strings to match the data inserted.

Comment: +1 varchar can still have trailing spaces wth SET ANSI_PADDING ON though

Comment: @gbn I've never looked up the what that setting actually does; Thanks for making me research it.  If I understand the documentation correctly, even with ANSI_PADDING ON, the VARCHAR(x) column will only contain trailing spaces if you explicitly put them there.

Comment: Correct, but it can cause [confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A27535+ansi_padding) Especially when it will be ON in later versions.

Answer (score 6):

This is a property of `CHAR` data type. If you want no extra spaces, you need to use `VARCHAR` although for a small field there is a minimal overhead compared to standard `CHAR`. Having said that, it is believed that `VARCHAR` nowadays is as good as `CHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

CHAR variables will store this extra padding, maybe you need to be using VARCHAR2 variables instead?

Answer (score 0):

`CHAR` represents a fixed-length data type in databases, while `VARCHAR` is employed for variable-length data. When data is stored in a database using `CHAR`, it maintains a constant length, padding any remaining space with additional characters, typically spaces, to meet the specified length.

On the other hand, `VARCHAR` accommodates variable-length data without padding. It only utilizes the necessary amount of storage for the actual data, without enforcing a fixed length. This flexibility makes `VARCHAR` suitable for storing content with varying sizes, optimizing storage space by not allocating unnecessary memory for padding